# Reference — does sizeof return the real memory size?

Tags: c++, reference, sizeof

I know this question has probably been asked in many different ways, but I'm adding my own because this is still unclear for me.

Consider this code:

```
long double q = 1.2;
long double &p = q;
cout << sizeof(p) << endl;`
```

`long double` is 12 bytes on my machine, and the output of the code is as expected 12 because as the standard says:

> When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the
>   size of the referenced type. (ISO C++ $5.3.3/2)

But as you most likely all know, references implementation is free, and thus, as the standard says again:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage (3.7).

So it seems that tomorrow I can come up with my own reference implementation that takes 200 bytes and make sure that the `sizeof` operator returns the right object size (instead of returning what would be the true implementation size of my reference)

So my question is actually extremely simple:

Can we rely on the `sizeof` operator to return the real memory occupation of a class when it contains, specifically, reference members?

Comment: You do realize that there's a big difference between taking the sizeof of a variable that happens to be a reference, and taking the sizeof a *type* that has a non-static data member that is a reference, right?

Comment: I don't even understand the question. Are you asking whether you can rely on sizeof telling you the correct size of something? Yes. Of course you can.

Comment: You do reaize that to do *So it seems that tomorrow i can come up with my own reference implementation that takes 200 bytes and make sure that the sizeof operator returns the right object size.* you would have to make your own compiler right?

Comment: If reference is implemented as pointer, then the p variable will take up the size of a pointer in memory, which obviously isn't what sizeof will return (12 bytes here)

Comment: @NathanOlivier, of course, but this is absolutely not the point of my question, please see my comment above

Comment: There is no control on what the reference is.  In many cases the compiler is free to use the original variable an omit the reference completely.

Comment: Read Nicol's comment above. If you have `struct S { long double& d; };` then `sizeof(S) != sizeof(long double)` on most platforms. The compiler does not get confused, it's not stupid. It doesn't implement `sizeof(S)` by adding together the result of applying sizeof to each member, so that it would get `sizeof(S::d)` which would be the size of the referenced type, not the storage needed for the reference.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 6):

Compare and contrast:

```
struct container {
  long double& dbl;
};

std::cout << sizeof(container::dbl) << '\n';
std::cout << sizeof(container)      << '\n';
```

([Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/KIhFJt))

One line tells you the size of a referred-to object. The other tells you the size of the structure containing the reference.

That behaviour is not by chance. It's defined by the standard and yes, you can rely on it.

There seems to be an assumption behind this question that the behaviour of the `sizeof` operator with a reference or reference type is somehow arbitrary and conventional. That is not the case; it falls out of the same logic that generally applies to references.

If I have

```
long double dbl;
```

then any use of `dbl` in its scope is an lvalue, which is to say a *reference*. That is necessary in order for it to be possible to assign a value to `dbl`. So the type of `dbl` (as revealed, for example, by `decltype(dbl)`) is `long double&`, not `long double`.

It would be ridiculous for `sizeof(dbl)` to return the size of the reference itself rather than the size of the referenced object.

Once you put the reference into a structure, you have a completely different beast. *As part of an object*, the reference occupies space, which cannot be optimized away unless the entire object containing it can be optimized away.

Comment: ok, pretty clear, so indeed as Nicol has pointed first, i was confused between size of a class/struct type vs size of a reference variable. Upvoted (+ Nicol's)

Comment: Well, i thought i got it perfectly but actually no : why do we actually have to make this distinction? between sizeof( a class containing a ref) and sizeof(a ref)?

Comment: This is what i understand from everything I read : in the case of a ref variable (see my example), the compiler would be easily able to make it completely disappear (thus printing the variable q directly), however, in some other (more complex than mine) cases, it might have to to keep track of it, thus having to really create a reference

Comment: Because of these two cases, I guess people concluded "well, let's s agree to make sizeof(reference) return the size of the referenced object. If my explanation is correct, does this mean that in the case of a struct containing a ref (your example), the reference member IS SYSTEMATICALLY CREATED? without the optim' i mentioned ? (make the variable disappear and point directly to the ref object)? This is the only explanation i see as to why both sizeof are different

Comment: @Romain227: If you create a struct containing a reference and the compiler cannot optimize away the existence of the container, then the struct object will necessarily contain the reference. It is not allowed for two instances of the same type to have different sizes, but in many cases the compiler can make entire variables vanish, provided that they have trivial constructors and destructors, that their addresses are never taken, and that their state is demonstrably immutable.

Comment: @Romain227: Note that you can't observe the optimization I just referred to, because pretty well every way of observing it would force the struct to exist :)

Comment: i have no probelm with sizeof(ref) returning the size of a referenced object. The thing that has always killed me is why do we have to make the distinction between sizeof(struct havign a ref) and sizeof(ref). And the only explanation i see, is as you said, is that in the case of a struct, the ref is always created physically in memory, whereas for a ref variable, the compiler can sometimes make it disappear, so in the end, its size doesn"t mean anything.

Comment: ..So people agreed for the ref variable to have the size of the referenced object. Plus, as you said, two objects instantiated from a class/struct necessarily have the same size, so either the ref member is created for each instance, either it is never created for any instance

Comment: @romain227: But that's not why sizeof a reference is what it is. It has to be the size of the referenced object in order for sizeof(var) to return the correct value. I did add that to the answer, in the end, since it seems to be an important point of understanding.

Comment: yeah i know, u were focusing on why sizeof(ref) is as it is, and i agree with you, but my own focus was the distinction with the struct :)

Comment: @Romain227: It took me a long time to really understand C++ references, too, and that was part of my struggle to accept C++ as a valid model. Probably my ill-informed rants are still kicking around to embarrass me. A variable declared as a reference is *not different* from a variable declared as a value. If I declared `double d, &rd=d`, both `d` and `rd` are of type `double&`; if they are used in a context which requires a value, the conversion will be automatic. But they are not different things. Putting a reference in a `struct`, however, is different.

Comment: It's clear for me now :) thanks for this discussion, that was very interesting ! (Upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

If you question if you can rely on `sizeof` of the following type:

```
struct A
{
   int& r;
};
```

Then yes - you can rely on `sizeof` in structs containing references.

E.g. this code is safe:

```
   char* buffer = new char[sizeof(A)];
   int value;
   A* valueRef = new (buffer) A{value};
```

You have enough bytes in buffer to store A object.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct S {
    long double& d;
};

static_assert(sizeof(S::d) == sizeof(long double));
static_assert(sizeof(S) != sizeof(S::d));  // true on most platforms
```

The compiler is smart enough to know the size of `S`, it doesn't get confused and think it is `sizeof(S::d)` because that would be stupid.